# How can I get column&row indices (number) for a specific element?

Tags: r

The contingency table of my data shows that there is one element with 21974 value. However, a `which` function cannot locate where it is. I am wondering if my code has an error or not.

I have the following code:

```
 table(as.numeric(dat[1,2:ncol(dat)]))
 # And the result is:
 #(Upper: Groups / Bottom: Frequency for each group)

53    58    59    60    65    67    71    72    74    75    78    79    80    81    82    84    88    89    94 21974 
143   142    70   226    63    95    89   181   147   344   131   896   480   205    84   159   351   475   364     1
```

There is one element in a group "21974".
However if I use a `which` function to figure out where it is, my code cannot locate it:

```
 which(dat[1,] == "21974", arr.ind=T)
```

Its result is:

```
     row col
```

I am not sure how this happens and would like to know if I misused the which function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `match`: `match(21974, df)` to give you a position in a vector such as df$colname. I think (I've not used it), this would work to find the position in the row as well:

```
df[match(21974,df$colname),]
```